# create mock of localstorage react

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this error:

> error : undefined | TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of
> undefined at request (C:\Users\amils\OneDrive\Documentos\Bootcamp -
> Training\Project\tracking-tool-webapp\src\api\utilities\fetch.js:45:26)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) at
> Object.getAll (C:\Users\amils\OneDrive\Documentos\Bootcamp -
> Training\Project\tracking-tool-webapp\src\api\utilities\provider.js:18:9)

the reason of this is because i have a token for execute my promise and this comes from local storage:

```
function onLoadCandidates(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.loading, payload: true });
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    apiCandidate
        .getAll(token)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.loading, payload: response.data });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: CandidatesActionTypes.Error, payload: err.message });
            LoggerService.error(err);
        });
}
```

my unit test is working until this part, after this it give me a error of undefined because the I dont have a local storage for token:

```
it('Should get all candidates', async () => {
            
            global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
                Promise.resolve({
                    status: 200,
                    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse),
                });
            });

            let result = await customRenderHook();
            let actions = result.current[1];

            localStorage.getItem = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('valuesss');
            await act(async () => {
                actions.onLoadCandidates();
            });

            let state = result.current[0];
            expect(state.candidates).toEqual(mockResponse);
        });
```

How I can mock the localStorage.getItem('token')? for this value not to be undefined

Answer (score 1):

Tests have their own local storage, so you need to set that value somewhere for example in beforeAll() test function.